# Jquery slider not working with graph

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I am trying to create a jquery slider that connects to data and moves an image on the graph as a jquery event is triggered. I've been able to create the slider, but it won't connect to my data and I haven't been able to get it to interact with the graph (or get the graph to show up on my webpage for that matter). This is for a class project so I really need to get it to work or risk failing the class... 
This is the code I have so far:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#Slider1").slider ({
            slide: function(event,ui){drawGraphs();}
    });
    $("#slider1’").each(
            function(){
                    $(this).slider("value",Math.random() * 100);
            }
    );

    drawGraphs();

    });

    function drawGraphs(){
    var cHeight = parseInt($("#Graph1").height());
    var cWidth = parseInt($("#Graph1").width());
    clearCanvas($("#Graph1"));
    clearCanvas($("#Graph2"));
    var canvas = document.getElementById("Graph1");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(graphPadding, graphPadding);
    ctx.lineTo(graphPadding,cHeight-graphPadding);
    ctx.lineTo(cWidth-graphPadding, cHeight-graphPadding);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    var availableSpace = cWidth-(graphPadding * 4);
    var horizSpace = availableSpace / 3;
    var vertSpace = cHeight -(graphPadding * 4);var points = new Array();
    for(var i = 0;i < 4;i++){
            var yPercent  = ($("#Slider1" + (i + 1)).slider("value") -100) * 
     -1;
            var yPos = (vertSpace * (yPercent / 100) + (graphPadding * 2));
            points.push(yPos);
    }
    var xPos = graphPadding * 2;
    ctx.beginPath();
    for(i = 0;i < 4;i++){
            if(i == 0){
                    ctx.moveTo(xPos, points[i]);
            }else{
                    ctx.lineTo(xPos, points[i]);
            }
            xPos += horizSpace;
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
     var xPos = graphPadding * 2;
    for(i = 0;i < 4;i++){
            drawCircle(ctx, xPos, points[i], 4, colours[i]);
            xPos += horizSpace;
    }
     var availableWidth = cWidth-(graphPadding * 6);
    var barWidth = availableWidth / 4;
    var maxHeight = cHeight- (graphPadding * 3);

    var xPos = graphPadding * 2;
    for(i = 0;i < 4;i++){
            // Work out height
            var h = maxHeight * ($("#Slider1" + (i + 1)).slider("value") / 
     100);
            var yPos = cHeight - h - (graphPadding * 2);
            ctx.fillStyle = colours[i];
            ctx.fillRect(xPos, yPos, barWidth, h);

            xPos += barWidth + graphPadding;

    }
    function clearCanvas(element){
    $(element).attr("width",$(element).attr("width"));
    }

    function drawCircle(ctx, x, y, radius, colour){
    ctx.fillStyle = colour;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius,0,Math.PI*2,true); 
    ctx.fill();

    }

    $(function() {   
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
    change: function(event, ui) {

    }
     });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include any console errors you may find and the various javascript libraries you are using. It may also be helpful to see your HTML elements as well.

Comment: It also looks like you are missing a `}` for your first function or your last function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a full example, it took soem time to determine what was wrong. I had to define `graphPadding` and `colours`. I found a number of syntax errors too.

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pfub6haf/

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <div class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-top">
    Sliders
  </div>
  <div class="ui-widget-content">
    <div id="slider-1" class="slide">
    </div>
    <div id="slider-2" class="slide">
    </div>
    <div id="slider-3" class="slide">
    </div>
    <div id="slider-4" class="slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-widget-header">
    Graphs
  </div>
  <div class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
    <canvas id="Graph1" class="graph" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
    <canvas id="Graph2" class="graph" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-widget-header {
  padding: .5em;
}

.slide {
  margin: .5em;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".slide").slider({
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      drawGraphs();
    }
  });
  $(".slide").each(
    function() {
      $(this).slider("value", Math.random() * 100);
    }
  );
  drawGraphs();
});

var graphPadding = 10;
var colours = [
  "rgb(255,0,0)",
  "rgb(255,255,0)",
  "rgb(0,255,0)",
  "rgb(0,0,255)"
];

function drawGraphs() {
  var cHeight = parseInt($("#Graph1").height());
  var cWidth = parseInt($("#Graph1").width());
  clearCanvas($("#Graph1"));
  clearCanvas($("#Graph2"));
  var canvas = $("#Graph1");
  var ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(graphPadding, graphPadding);
  ctx.lineTo(graphPadding, cHeight - graphPadding);
  ctx.lineTo(cWidth - graphPadding, cHeight - graphPadding);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  var availableSpace = cWidth - (graphPadding * 4);
  var horizSpace = availableSpace / 3;
  var vertSpace = cHeight - (graphPadding * 4);
  var points = new Array();
  /*
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var yPercent = ($("#Slider1" + (i + 1)).slider("value") - 100) * -1;
    var yPos = (vertSpace * (yPercent / 100) + (graphPadding * 2));
    points.push(yPos);
  }
  */
  $(".slide").each(function(ind, el) {
    var yPercent = ($(el).slider("value") - 100) * -1;
    var yPos = (vertSpace * (yPercent / 100) + (graphPadding * 2));
    points.push(yPos);
  });
  console.log("Points: ", points);
  var xPos = graphPadding * 2;
  ctx.beginPath();
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      ctx.moveTo(xPos, points[i]);
    } else {
      ctx.lineTo(xPos, points[i]);
    }
    xPos += horizSpace;
  }
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  var xPos = graphPadding * 2;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    drawCircle(ctx, xPos, points[i], 4, colours[i]);
    xPos += horizSpace;
  }
  var availableWidth = cWidth - (graphPadding * 6);
  var barWidth = availableWidth / 4;
  var maxHeight = cHeight - (graphPadding * 3);
  var xPos = graphPadding * 2;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    // Work out height
    var h = maxHeight * ($("#Slider1" + (i + 1)).slider("value") /
      100);
    var yPos = cHeight - h - (graphPadding * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = colours[i];
    ctx.fillRect(xPos, yPos, barWidth, h);
    xPos += barWidth + graphPadding;
  }
}

function clearCanvas(element) {
  $(element).attr("width", $(element).attr("width"));
}

function drawCircle(ctx, x, y, radius, colour) {
  ctx.fillStyle = colour;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.fill();
}
```

Using the `class` attribute, I can more easily make use of selectors and iterate over each slider. Since I am applying the same code to all 4, I can just use `$(".slide")` as the selector.

Since you're using jQuery, I made some minor changes in your draw code. For example:

```
var canvas = $("#Graph1");
var ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");
```

has the same effect as:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("Graph1");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Since jQuery uses Objects, you can call on the first index and get the DOM element.

Making use of `.each()` we could grow to have a larger or smaller number of points and sliders. It makes the code more portable.

You can also make use of the `data` attribute to store more info. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/pfub6haf/3/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Cleaned up some more issues and applied more theming: https://jsfiddle.net/pfub6haf/8/